# Cache storage works fine in chrome PWA but can't work in IOS pwa

Tags: progressive-web-apps, browser-cache, vite

I'm running vue.js app using vite and everything works fine in `chrome/firefox` browsers. also the basic functionality works fine on safari and IOS. I'm trying to access the cache storage and sync token between `pwa` app and safari browser.

###### Two weird things happens:

1. When user login to the website I set the cache and I simulate user behavior. for example a basic user login and then change the url to something else and back to the website. When this thing happens the `caches` variable is undefined...
2. When I set cache and user installs `pwa` there's no data stored in cache storage.

Note: I persist cache in `local-storage` of the browser and I know that I can't use local-storage to get token thus I use cache to share it between browser and pwa

###### Codes

How I cache token:

```js
const CACHE_NAME = "auth";
const TOKEN_KEY = "token";
const FAKE_ENDPOINT = "/get-token";


export const saveToken = async (token: string) => {
    try {
        const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
        const responseBody = JSON.stringify({
            [TOKEN_KEY]: token
        });
        const response = new Response(responseBody);
        await cache.put(FAKE_ENDPOINT, response);
        console.log("Token saved! ");
        console.log("Saved token: ", await getToken())
    } catch (error) {
        // It's up to you how you resolve the error
        console.log("saveToken error:", {error});
    }
};

export const getToken = async () => {
    try {
        const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
        const response = await cache.match(FAKE_ENDPOINT);

        if (!response) {
            return null;
        }

        const responseBody = await response.json();
        return responseBody[TOKEN_KEY];
    } catch (error) {
        // Gotta catch 'em all
        console.log("getToken error:", {error});
    }
};
```

Comment: I think there's a bug in Safari core. so there's no way to access cache storage in PWA standalone mode! if you want to know more please follow the link: https://github.com/PWA-POLICE/pwa-bugs